# How to customize message in maestro mail notification

Tags: emails

I am working on Maestro module. we have interactive tasks in the Maestro which are executed by the users to whom task is assigned. In Maestro, we can intimate the user by mail about the task assigned to him. Message in the mail is one paragraph. I want to customize this mail. I need to add table and send message in multiple pargagraphs.

I have tried adding br(I tried adding angular brackets but text after that is going to next line) in the message but message is being displayed along with br instead of going to new line.

I think html tags doesn't work there.

How to make html tags work in the custom mail or customise the message?
P.S: I am attaching the screenshot where I am writing the message[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been up for a while but thought I would answer. Up until recently, Maestro was removing any HTML from that textbox using Drupal's checkPlain.

I added a patch which was accepted into the development branch so it should be sorted in the next release of Maestro. If you wanted a fix in the meantime, use the patch file here: https://www.drupal.org/project/maestro/issues/3076536